# Absurdum est, affirmare, re credendum esse non judici

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification

I have trouble understanding the grammar of this sentence, especially *re*:

> Absurdum est, affirmare, re credendum esse non judici.

> It is absurd to affirm, that we must not give credit to a judge.

from "A Translation and Explanation of the Principal Technical Terms and Phrases…" by Halkerston.

I get that *re credendum esse non judici* is indirect speech but the ablative *re* really puzzles me.

Comment: I found [at least one example](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Law_Lexicon_Or_Dictionary_of_Jurispruden/pwtLAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22rei+credendum+esse%22&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover) of *rei credendum esse*, which makes a lot more sense to my ear.

Comment: @brianpck: I was wondering why, for the gerundive-of-obligation, the ablative, "re" was used; yourself has corrected it to, "rei". Why is "iudici" in the genitive? Why not use a passive infinitive giving: "It is absurd that the matter should be believed and is not to be judged/ considered,"?

Comment: @tony I interpret both as dative, i.e. "It is absurd to affirm that we should believe in a thing, not in a judge."

Comment: @brianpck: I thought it was "iudicium"--"judgement"; not "iudex"--"judge". Thanks.

Comment: Could *re* not simply mean something like, "in a case": "It is absurd, that one ought not to trust the judge in a case*?